# Get time when Azure VM status gets changed

Tags: python, azure

I stopped the instance and was looking for the time when it reached stopped state. But I cannot find much in the documentation on how can I lookup that information.

On the portal, I see the activity log, but I hope I don't have to make yet another api call (I am doing a list + get on each VM with expand view).

I am using azure python sdk and looking at the api for the [InstanceViewStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/instanceview#instanceviewstatus) I believe the `time` field should be populated (I might be wrong):

> vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get("myRG", "myVM", expand='instanceView')
>
> vm.instance_view.statuses[1].__dict__
>   {'time': None, 'code': 'PowerState/deallocated', 'display_status': 'VM deallocated', 'level': , 'message': None}

My question is, how can I get the time when the instance status moved to stopped state or running state using the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how can I get the time when the instance status moved to stopped state or running state using the sdk?

You almost get the answer.

```
vms = computeClient.virtual_machines.get("resourceGroup","vm",expand="instanceView")

time = vms.instance_view.statuses[0].time
```

Based on my understanding, `vms.instance_view.statuses[1]` stands for current status of VM, so there is no time for it. If you use [InstanceViewStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/instanceview#instanceviewstatus), you will also  get the same result.